# Angular js $resource error when calling query on $resource with path parameter

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc, angular-resource

I am trying to hit an ajax call using $resource of angular js to get an array of objects.I am passing an path variable which is an id for the object and when i try to call query on $resource , it shows error given below.resource and controller code is given below.
i am using Spring MVC on backend, for rest controller of spring code is given below.Please give some suggestions, what i am doing wrong here and what is the best practice?
this is the error in console -

```
TypeError: V is not a function
at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-resource/1.6.1/angular-resource.min.js:13:165
at n (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:7:427)
at C.setUrlParams (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-resource/1.6.1/angular-resource.min.js:13:50)
at Function.l.(anonymous function) [as query] (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-resource/1.6.1/angular-resource.min.js:10:156)
at Object.getSubCategoryIdNameFn [as getSubCategoryIdName] (http://localhost:8080/MyCoupon/resources/js/category/category_service.js:17:71)
at r.$scope.catChanged (http://localhost:8080/MyCoupon/resources/js/coupon/coupon_controller.js:13:19)
at fn (eval at compile (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:213:110), <anonymous>:4:221)
at r.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:133:313)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:252:529
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:264:447
```

and here are my service and controller code -

```
function getSubCategoryIdNameFn(catId){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $resource("admin/rest/subcategory-id-name/:catId",{catId:"@catId"}).query({catId:catId})
    .$promise
    .then(function(response){
        deferred.resolve(response);
    },function(error){
        deferred.reject(error);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

controller -

```
$scope.catChanged = function (){
    categoryService.getSubCategoryIdName($scope.coupon.category).then(function(response){
        $scope.subcatList = response;
    },function(error){

    });
}
```

i am new to angular, so have no idea what the console error saying?
server side controller is in spring -

```
@RequestMapping(value="subcategory-id-name/{catId}", method=RequestMethod.GET,produces={"application/json"})
public List<SubCategory> getSubCategoryIdAndName(@PathVariable int catId){
    return subCategoryService.getSubCategoryIdName(catId);
}
```

Comment: There is no need to manufacture a promise with `$q.defer` as `$promise` is already a promise. Just return that.

Comment: Use `angular.js` instead of the minified version. The stack trace will be more meaningful.

Comment: The most likely cause of the problem is that the code mixes angular.js v1.4.8 with angular-resource.js v1.6.1. Make sure the two use the same version.

Comment: thanks georgeawg, changing the version of resource.js worked (Y)